# Angular2: removeAll() in RethinkDB with Horizon API

Tags: angular, typescript, rethinkdb, removeall, horizon

I'm pretty new with Angular2, RethinkDB and Horizon API and I'm building a small webapp. In this app I'm trying to delete all objects in a specific table, and therefore I use the fetch() and removeAll() functions from Horizon API. The problem is the following error:

```
removeAll takes an array as an argument
```

The Horizon API's documentation is describing that the fetch() method returns an array, and I'm using this array to removeAll() data.
**Source:** https://horizon.io/api/collection/#fetch

```
this.table.removeAll(this.table.fetch().subscribe(
  result => console.log('Result:', result),
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log('Results fetched')
));
```

When I log the result of this fetch, it's displaying an array of Objects.

```
Result: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I've tried declaring an array earlier and many other things but nothing seems to work. Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close but you're calling removeAll the wrong way. An example would be this:

```
ClearTable(): void {
    this.table.fetch().subscribe(
      (returnObjects: Object[]) => {
        this.table.removeAll(returnObjects);
      }
    );
}
```

You can only manipulate the objects when you subscribe to them. Pass them to an array and now you've got the right objects to pass to the removeAll function